# Sublime Text conditional find and replace

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext

It is possible to do a conditional find and replace in sublime text? I want to remove the external div class = "key-actions" but keep anything within them. The problem is the internal content will always be the same with maybe 3 different links at times

```
// this becomes
<div class="key-actions">
  <a href="one-link.html"><div class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-left"><i class="icon-chevron-sign-right icon-showhouse2"></i> One Link</div></a>
  <a href="two-link.html"><div class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-left"><i class="icon-chevron-sign-right icon-showhouse2"></i> Two Link</div></a>
</div>

// this
<a href="one-link.html"><div class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-left"><i class="icon-chevron-sign-right icon-showhouse2"></i> One Link</div></a>
<a href="two-link.html"><div class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-left"><i class="icon-chevron-sign-right icon-showhouse2"></i> Two Link</div></a>
```

Comment: This should be able to be done using regex - I retagged your question so the regex masters will see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of dependent on your code formatting, in particular the position of your new lines, but the following works for your example.

Find what:

```
(?s)<div class="key-actions">(.+?)\n</div>
```

Replace with:

```
\1
```

This will only work if there are no divs inside `<div class="key-actions">` that close on a new line.